# OpenVPN assign client same ip address as static address on router network

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat, bridge

I have an OpenVPN server running on a machine behind my home router, and two clients, one Macbook and one iPhone.

When I'm not using OpenVPN, I can statically assign IP addresses to the Macbook and iPhone, `192.168.X.*` through the router web interface and the device network settings. The configuration I'm using for OpenVPN is the `10.8.0.0` network with the server running on `10.8.0.1` and the two clients statically assigned IPs from `client-config-dir` in the range `10.8.0.*`.

The setup that I have uses the `tun` interface, and I'm able to forward all internet traffic perfectly with all the devices mentioned. I'm able to `ssh` from my clients to the devices inside my `192.168.X.*` LAN network, but I would like to be able to `ssh` from machines on my LAN network to the OpenVPN clients using the `192.168.X.*` addresses rather than using `10.8.0.*`. I have the `/etc/hosts` hostname pointing to the `192.168.X.*` address when resolving the hostname.

I have seen online that OpenVPN does not support `tap` tunnels on iOS, so I'm not sure if ethernet bridging would be a solution.

Is there a way to give the clients the same static IP addresses on `192.168.X.*` when they are connected through OpenVPN? I would like to be able to access these devices with the same static ip whether the OpenVPN is used or not. I would be more than happy to provide additional details as necessary!